# Unable to copy async data to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm making an API call whose result is displayed in a table. Say, the columns are 'isbn', 'name of book', 'published year'. Every row would have a copy to clipboard icon that would copy the isbn value into clipboard.

To be specific, I'm unable to copy the data["isbn"] into the clipboard, when the user clicks the copy button.

What I tried to do was to obtain the data["isbn"] and store it as foo's (input id = 'foo') value. As clipboard functions work with elements like input, etc.

*Code:*

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.8/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<script>
async function books_data{

const response = await fetch('/books');
const data = await response.json();

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

document.getElementById("foo").value = val["JobID"];

cell1.innerHTML = data["isbn"];
cell2.innerHTML = data["name"];
cell3.innerHTML = data["year"];
cell4.innerHTML = '<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#foo"> Copy to clipboard </button>" ';

}
</script>
<div>
  <input id="foo" style="display: none">
...
...

</div>
```

I'm unclear where I'm going wrong. I referred these:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand, https://clipboardjs.com/

The most popular method for Copy to Clipboard is involving Document.execCommand, which seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Have you tried `navigator.clipboard.writeText("some String")` ?

Comment: @Keith I did. However, I'm getting a syntax error- Unexpected end of input. `cell4.innerHTML = '<button type = "submit" onclick="() => navigator.clipboard.writeText("Copy this text to clipboard")"> Copy to Clipboard </button>'; `

Comment: You are using double quotes for your writeText, and double quotes to enclose your script, the error has nothing to do with using writeText, try escaping the double quotes `.writeText(/"xxxx/")`.  On a side note using `innerHTML` is not the best way to be writing code.

Comment: @Keith, I tried escaping the double quotes and received 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /', while innerHTML is not the best way to code, I'm currently trying to run the navigator.clipboard.writeText("some String") successfully. Also, I had used innerHTML in order to dynamically fill in table values from the response json, but if I may, I would like your suggestions on a better alternative to innerHTML later.

Comment: My mistake it's the other slash  \ not `/`. Eg.  `"hello \" there"` would give you `hello " there`.

Comment: `cell3.innerHTML = '<button type = "submit" onclick="() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(\"Copy this text to clipboard\")"> Copy  </button>';` is what I tried. And 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input' is what I'm getting

Comment: You have quotes inside quotes inside quotes,,..  It's not the nicest way to code.   But anyway,  try -> `'<button type = "submit" onclick="() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(\'Copy this text to clipboard\')"> Copy  </button>'`

Comment: Well, this snippet gave no error or warnings in the Console, the fact, as you have rightly mentioned that it isn't a good way to code, somehow the 'Copy' button in the table does not seem to work. So, when I click it, what I was expecting is 'Copy this text to clipboard' to get into my clipboard. But it doesn't. And I'm not getting any errors or warnings either. I'm sorry, I'm just a bit new to web dev. I'm not sure if I am going wrong with the buttons in the table. Other buttons works just fine :(